# Page safety of setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a piece of text that uses Webkit's `background-clip:text` feature and for pure aesthetics purposes, I want to include a script to scroll through the image on the text. The one way I have thought of doing this is using `setInterval` and running the function I have included below. I want to know if I will run into any problems of using `setInterval` since I have it looping at 50ms.

Function:

```
function movePos(){
    var obj = document.querySelector('h1 span');
    var pos = parseInt(obj.style.backgroundPositionY);
    obj.style.backgroundPositionY = (pos + 1) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: I don't think you run into any problems. Maybe it is safer to use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any modern browser with even modest hardware should be able to handle executing these three lines of code 20 times per second. You should be fine.

If you want to optimize, and the `obj` variable won't change, you could cache that value so you're not running a selector 20 times per second. I'm not certain, but this is probably the most CPU intensive of the three lines of code.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I have personally built and run many physics engines in JS that rely on a differential equation solver wrapped in a loop which executes 50+ times per frame with 60 frames per second. That's 16.66ms. Your use of the DOM will certainly slow things down, but not to the degree that you need to worry about it.